# PySpark is not able to read Hive ORC transaction table through sparkContext/hiveContext ? Can we update/delete hive table data using Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried to access the Hive ORC Transactional table (which has underlying delta files on HDFS) using PySpark but I'm not able to read the transactional table through sparkContext/hiveContext.

/mydim/delta_0117202_0117202

/mydim/delta_0117203_0117203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Officially **`Spark`** not yet supported for **Hive-ACID** table, get a
>   **`full dump/incremental dump of acid table`** to regular **`hive orc/parquet`** partitioned table then read the data using spark.

There is a Open Jira [saprk-15348](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15348) to add support for reading **`Hive ACID`** table.

- If you run **`major compaction`** on Acid table(from hive) then spark able to read **`base_XXX`** directories only but not delta directories [Spark-16996](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16996) addressed in this jira.
- There are some workaround to read acid tables using [SPARK-LLAP](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/156816/hive-transactional-tables-are-not-readable-by-spar.html) as mentioned in this link.
- **I think** starting from **`HDP-3.X`** [HiveWareHouseConnector](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehouseconnector_for_handling_apache_spark_data.html) is able to support to read HiveAcid tables.

Comment: I've tested this.
From CDP - HDP-3.0, using the Hive Warehouse Connector library/plugin with Spark will enable ACID compliance for Hive tables(ORC format Tables)